# How to use CIS Benchmarks without being a CIS member

Tags: audit, compliance

I am trying to audit my Linux systems with the [CIS security benchmarks](https://www.cisecurity.org/cis-benchmarks/). There are OS tools like [OpenSCAP](https://www.open-scap.org/) or [Lynis](https://cisofy.com/lynis/) that can do security-related benchmarks, and come with some benchmarks which might be *close* to the CIS benchmarks but are not the same.

Has anyone gone through the chore of converting the freely available Benchmarks in PDF form and converted them into something that can be fed to OpenSCAP or Lynis and made the result publicly available?

I have searched but could not find something, but maybe I have overlooked something.

Comment: you mean like: https://www.tenable.com/downloads/cis-compliance-audit-policies

Comment: @schroeder yes, something like the tenable link (which is pretty cool), however the license forbids usage in other scripts without consent from tenable ... well, seems fair in the light of all the work they put in. I also see your point about this question being off topic - any suggestion on how I can solve my concrete problem (getting CIS benchmarks without paying the license)?

Comment: Given the copyright issues and licenses involved (not to mention the work involved), I'm not sure you are going to find anything legitimate. It IS an interesting question, though.

Comment: All right, Benchmarks are licensed as Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/legalcode). Also, any transformation is not allowed to be called "CIS" Benchmark. So that is the dealbreaker here - we will either need to get a membership, or do something else.

Comment: @Isaac you could get a CIS partner to do the evaluation for you.  Their membership would cover you.  I know a company that provides a complimentary CIS evaluation of enterprises.

Comment: @DarkMatter That is good to know, however in this case we would need to have ongoing evaluations, and since the environment is rather sensible, the less third partys the better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the legal side of things - which basically explains why I could not find anything useful. In short: You cannot use CIS Benchmarks **and call them CIS Benchmarks** without being a member.

Quoting from the "Terms of Use" of one of the PDFs that are provided freely:

> Terms of Use
>   This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International Public License. The link to the license terms can be found at https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/legalcode
>   To further clarify the Creative Commons license related to CIS Benchmark content, you are authorized to copy and redistribute the content for use by you, within your organization and outside your organization for non-commercial purposes only, provided that (i) appropriate credit is given to CIS, (ii) a link to the license is provided. Additionally, **if you remix, transform** or build upon the CIS Benchmark(s), you may only distribute the modified materials if they are subject to the same license terms as the original Benchmark license and **your derivative will no longer be a CIS Benchmark**. Commercial use of CIS Benchmarks is subject to the prior approval of the Center for Internet Security.

[emphasis mine]

In short: If I transform that PDF into some sort of script, I can no longer call it "a CIS Benchmark". Also, no commercial use.

So if you really need your asset to be CIS benchmarked, there is no way around a membership. [Cost-wise](https://www.cisecurity.org/cis-securesuite/pricing-and-categories/) it's not as bad as I thought, but might be difficult for very small organisations.

[Tenable](https://www.tenable.com/downloads/cis-compliance-audit-policies) publishes a machine-readable form, however it also has a restrictive license, so again, there is no way around paying.

If its "just" security that one is interested in, there are, of course, various good alternatives (see question), and a lot of them seem to be CIS inspired (or the other way around). But in our case, our customers were asking about CIS, so we need to get a membership.

Comment: I want to chime in here on cost, since it was metioned - if you're a State, Local, Tribal or Territorial Government (SLTT), you can just join the MS-ISAC for free and become a CIS member without any cost. (Center for Internet Security is the focal point of the MS-ISAC so they kinda go hand in hand.)

Comment: I am getting a similar problem and cant find the exact answer. We have the following requirements from our clients:

"CompanyA utilises the (CIS) Security Controls in order to assess/evaluate and monitor IT security in IT systems. Suppliers that manage our IT
systems shall actively support us in achieving compliance with CIS Security Controls and provide regular reports based on the CIS Security Controls."

So if we implements CIS benchmarks via script to hardening the security in our IT environment and share the reports to our clients then this mean we should first have a CIS membership?

Comment: This is my understanding. Alternatively your client could have the membership. In fact, if they require it, they might allready have it.
That beeing said, I have not looked into the subject for years, so the situation might have changed.